# How do I fix "Unable to resolve type from namespace" error in AvaloniaUI XAML window definition?

Tags: wpf, xaml, .net-core, avaloniaui

I've been working with the DevExpress MVVM assembly (.Net Core).
I created a version of the assembly that uses AvaloniaUI in place of WPF.

I'm including this assembly in my client project and am having difficulty with name space resolution in a XAML definition. I' using the above mentioned MVVM assembly (using AvaloniaUI) in place of the default version.

**Consider the following XAML definition:**

```
<Window x:Class="Moonshot_Foundry_Core.Views.MainWindowView"
 xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
 xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
 xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Sample.Views"
 xmlns:productionViewModels="clr-namespace:Sample.ViewModels.Production"
 xmlns:designViewModels="clr-namespace:Sample.ViewModels.Designer"
 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
 mc:Ignorable="d" Title="Sample" Height="720" Width="1280" 
 DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type=productionViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}"
 d:DataContext="{dxmvvm:ViewModelSource Type=designViewModels:MainWindowViewModel}">
```

**I get the following error:**

> Error XAMLIL Unable to resolve type ViewModelSource from namespace
>   http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm (line 13 position
>   9) Line 13, position 9.

I recall reading somewhere that I should try using the referenced assembly rather than the URL in the namespace definition. I'm unsure on how to do this.

Can someone help shed some light on how to debug this or what the possible resolution might be?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a namespace declaration using the referenced assembly in place of the URL: (replace the **v19.1** with your referenced version)

```
xmlns:dxmvvm="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Mvvm.POCO;assembly=DevExpress.Mvvm.v19.1"
```

In my case, I was having a similar issue where I created a new DevExpress project, and it created the MainWindow.xaml with the **assembly** namespace declaration, but it would not build and I had to replace it with the **URL** declaration to get it working:

```
xmlns:dxmvvm="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/mvvm"
```

Perhaps the opposite will work in your case.

Also note that if the project builds and runs, any errors regarding the namespace declarations are likely not an issue - it's just the XAML parser not being able to get full access to the (un)built assembly and you are likely fine to ignore these errors if you're able to run your application.